# Batch How to start a program

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file to launch my executable file after it has made some changes to itself.

My batch file is:

```
START /D "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.exe"
```

When I run it though I just get a brief console flash and Test.exe doesn't start up.

I've verified the EXE is there in the directory.
I've launched the exe manually to verify it is working as well.

My batch file resides in

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\run.bat"
```

Comment: `/D` means starting directory. Remove it.

Comment: When I put it without /d I get a command prompt window displayed but my Test.exe doesn't start

Comment: It's probably thinking your argument is a title (see `start /?`). Try `start "" "c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\test\test.exe"`.

Comment: Always run your batch scripts from the command prompt instead of double-clicking them. This way, you can actually read what the error you get is.

Answer (score 9):

There are two issues:

1. The `/D` option solely defines the starting or working directory, but not the program to execute.
2. The `start` command considers the first quoted argument as the title of the new window. To avoid confusion with other arguments, always provide a window title (that may also be empty).

There are two solutions, which are actually not exactly equivalent:

1. Remove the `/D` option, so the current working directory is used:

   ```
   start "" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.exe"
   ```
2. Keep the `/D` option and explicitly provide the new working directory to be used:

   ```
   start "" /D "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test" "Test.exe"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try changing to this

```
start /d "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test" Test.exe
```

You will see the console flash and your program should startup.

**Update**

Thanks for @SomethingDark 's suggestion to use the following code.

```
start "" C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.exe
```

However, the above code will not work if your filename contains space.

Comment: You have an extra quote and the `/D` flag doesn't belong.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks. what does it mean by `/D flag doesn't belong`?

Comment: It means take it out and use the full path instead. `start "" C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.exe`

Comment: I'm getting error `Windows cannot find the file. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.` but with the code I provided above, the`exe` file opened successfully.

Comment: @SomethingDark I found out why it didn't work. Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command.Add it to your batch script.Notice that you have to add double quotes after start keyword if there is/are whitespaces in the path string.

```
start "" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

Enclose any directory names which are longer than one-word into quotation marks. So the following path:

```
   start C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQL.exe
```

Should become something like this:

```
   start C:\"Program Files"\MySQL\"MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE"\MySQL.exe
```

Comment: I know that it works, but *please* - don't do that. Always quote the complete path: `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQL.exe"` (and add a pseudo-title instead: `start "" "blah blah"`)